logstash mutate json object
How can I use logstash mutate filter to convert from
{"a":{"b":"str1", "c":"str2",...}}

to
{"b":"str1", "c":"str2",...}


Ah, nevermind.I guess this does the job
rename => { "[a][b]" => "b" }
rename => { "[a][c]" => "c" }

